# Use buttons for scrolling in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, scroll

I want our users to be able to **scroll with buttons**  within a combobox.

I've customized the `style` and `ItemContainerStyle` of a `ComboBox`

Now I don't know how to access the `ScrollViewer` in my `ComboBox` from code-behind, and add event handlers for the buttons. I think i'm on the right way, but i'm stuck at this point.

This is what I want to accomplish:

[image: the goal]

- My `ComboBox` in my `MainWindow`:

  ```
  <ComboBox x:Name="cb" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{staticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}" 
              IsDropDownOpen="True">
      <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem"/>
  </ComboBox>
  ```

My `ItemcontainerStyle`:

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE8E8E8"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Padding="0,10" Margin="0">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF214174"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE8E8E8"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Style of `ComboBox`:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Popup Margin="0" x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true"
                    IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalOffset="0" OverridesDefaultStyle="False">

                        <Border Name="DropDownBorder" Width="150" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="250">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,4" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF001940" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0"  CanContentScroll="true" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,40" Padding="0" Foreground="#00000000">
                                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="0"  />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Rows="1" Columns="2" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <RepeatButton Width="50" Background="#00000000" Content="Up" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False"></RepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Width="50" Background="#00000000" Content="Down" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False"></RepeatButton>
                                    </UniformGrid>
                                </Grid>
                    </Border>
                        </Popup>
                        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource cmbToggle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="0,0,21,0"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `ScrollViewer` a name to access it. You can also keep this just in xaml quite easily for the functionality you desire:

so say I specify the `ScrollViewer` name to:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="someScroll"
              ...>
```

Now modify your `RepeatButton`'s to:

```
<RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=someScroll}"
              ... />
<RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=someScroll}"
              ... />
```

[ScrollBar Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar_fields.aspx) lists other commands available for use similar to `ScrollBar.LineDownCommand` / `ScrollBar.LineUpCommand`

Comment: Even better! Thanks. However i still have an issue: If nothing is "mouseover-selected" scrolling works fine. But when something is selected, it will scroll through "my items" instead of the scrollviewer itself. How can I resolve that ?

Comment: @DeMama That does seem strange. However not sure it's related to the Command as even without the Command specified, I can see just mouse-over seems to scroll the viewer automatically. I'll have a look later when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you name the `ScrollViewer`, then it is easy to access it:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0"  CanContentScroll="true" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,40" Padding="0" Foreground="#00000000">
    <ItemsPresenter Margin="0"  />
</ScrollViewer>
```

You should then be able to access it like so:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)cb.Template.FindName("ScrollViewer", cb);
```